# convert array to hash using grep and map in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have an array as follows:

```
@array = ('a:b','c:d','e:f:g','h:j');
```

How can I convert this into the following using grep and map?

```
%hash={a=>1,b=>1,c=>1,d=>1,e=>1,f=>1,h=>1,j=>1};
```

I've tried:

```
 @arr;

 foreach(@array){
    @a = split ':' , $_;
    push @arr,@a;

 } 


  %hash = map {$_=>1} @arr;
```

but i am getting all the values i should get first two values of an individual array

Comment: Are you wanting `g` also?

Comment: @JasonGray: He says, *”i should get first two values of an individual array”*

Answer (score 4):

Its very easy:

```
%hash = map {$_=>1} grep { defined $_ } map { (split /:/, $_)[0..1] } @array;
```

So, you **split** each array element with ":" delimiter, getting bigger array, take only 2 first values; then grep defined values and pass it to other **map** makng key-value pairs.

Comment: @Borodin Thats cus if `split` return array with size 1, slice `[0..1]` will return 2 elements anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ignore everything except first two elements after `split`,

```
 my @arr;
 foreach (@array){
    @a = split ':', $_;
    push @arr, @a[0,1];
 } 

  my %hash = map {$_=>1} @arr;
```

Using map,

```
my %hash =
  map { $_ => 1 }
  map { (split /:/)[0,1] }
  @array;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work though not elegent enough. I use a temporary array to hold the result of `split` and return the first two elements.

```
my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } map { my @t = split ':', $_; $t[0], $t[1] } @array;
```

Answer (score 1):

This filters out `g` key

```
my %hash = map { map { $_ => 1; } (split /:/)[0,1]; } @array;
```